# Joomla login text alignment

Tags: joomla, authentication

I want the login text to be aligned in left for text "Forgot your password? Forgot your username? Create an account"

http://techcongress.net/2013/index.php/exhibit

Answer (score 0):

Create a template override. Just copy the modules/mod_login/tmpl to /templates/your_template/html/mod_login/ and edit it, wrap the 2 input fields in a div and the links in another; float both to the left.

Comment: Now why this http://techcongress.net/2013/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/users-component/login-form ERROR ??

Misaligned here again

Comment: Add this rule to your custom css: #inner_content .login {margin:50px 0 0 210px}